# Push notifications PHP Remove bad Regid

Tags: php, curl, google-cloud-messaging

I am wondering how can I look through curl and find out which of my regIds in PHP were invalid for one reason or another so I can remove them from server.  I am still testing and I purposefully put two that are bad and one that is good, so I am getting one success and two failures, how do I get the script to find the failures?

```
<?php
function sendNotification($title  ,$message , $registrationIds)
    {
        require_once'config.php';
        $msg = array
                    (
                'message'               => $message,
                'title'                 => $title
            );
        $feilds = array
            (
                'registration_ids'      => $registrationIds,
                'data'                  => $msg
            );
        $headers = array
            (
                'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );
        $ch = curl_init();

        #Sending the packet
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($feilds));
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $err = curl_errno($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        if ( !$result ) 
        {
            echo "<br />"; 
            echo "Error: ' $err'"; 
        }
        return $result;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Are you not getting a error response when you send to an invalid token?

Comment: I'm getting error responses, that's the failures I am getting, I am wondering how to get the RegId's of the failures.